# Can ASP.NET Core auto close idle websocket connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I use ASP.NET Core 6 to create a WebSocket service, my code like this:

```cs
app.UseWebSockets(new WebSocketOptions()
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    AllowedOrigins = { "*" }
});

app.MapControllers();
```

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<WebSocketState> _invalidWebSocketStateList = new[]
        { WebSocketState.CloseReceived, WebSocketState.Closed, WebSocketState.Aborted };

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest == false)
        {
            return Ok("end");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            var sendDate = new List<DataInfo>();
            // do some thing
            var valBytes =
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(sendDate));
            var mem = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(valBytes);
            await websocket.SendAsync(mem, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            // try
            // {
            //     var receive = new Memory<byte>(new byte[10]);
            //     using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            //     cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1 * 1500));
            //     var receiveResult = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(receive, cts.Token);
            // }
            // catch (OperationCanceledException)
            // {
            // }

            if (_invalidWebSocketStateList.Contains(websocket.State))
            {
                await websocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
                break;
            }
        }

        return Ok("websocket closed");
    }
}
```

When the user closes the browser tab, the WebSocket connection is not needed anymore, so the server should close the connection.

But if I did not use the `websocket.ReceiveAsync` method, the `websocket.State` is stil open and the server still pushes data.

Is there any way to close the WebSocket connection not use `ReceiveAsync` method when the client close the connection?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should have a pending ReceiveAsync call on the websocket so you can detect graceful and ungraceful closes.

Comment: Use ping/pong can check whether the client is alive or not, so whether the server can close the connection if check the client is leaving?